# How can I keep sRGB Color Values in sync across various Xcode functionalities

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, uinavigationbar, srgb

I am trying to set the UI colors for a navigation bar control in an iPhone app to values detailed in a specification document, but I cannot get Xcode to maintain the correct colors across it's various functions. The color of the navigation bar should be set to srgb values 5x199x231, but when I set these values using the Xcode color tool in the Utilities panel, both the storyboard and the simulator show different colors (25x187x225 and 0x187x227 respectively). I'm left with an app that doesn't have the corect colors and I can't seem to get Xcode to synchronize the values. I am using the DigitalColor Meter to make the srgb measurements. Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As far as I know, iOS doesn't even support color management (no ColorSync), so even if you get the right values into Xcode, they'll potentially display differently on different iOS devices.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I just tested the values on another Mac and got 3 completely different color readings!